# Override default Spring-Boot application.properties settings in Junit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot application where the default properties are set in an `application.properties` file in the classpath (src/main/resources/application.properties).

I would like to override some default settings in my JUnit test with properties declared in a `test.properties` file (src/test/resources/test.properties)

I usualy have a dedicated Config Class for my Junit Tests, e.g.

```
package foo.bar.test;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import(CoreConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

}
```

I first thought that using `@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")` in  the TestConfig class would do the trick, but these properties will not overwrite the application.properties settings (see Spring-Boot Reference Doc - [23. Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config)).

Then I tried to use `-Dspring.config.location=classpath:test.properties` when invoking the test. That was successful - but I don't want to set this system property for each test execution. Thus I put it in the code

```
@Configuration
@Import(CoreConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

  static {
    System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "classpath:test.properties");
  }

}
```

which unfortunatly was again not successful.

There must be a simple solution on how to override `application.properties` settings in JUnit tests with `test.properties` that I must have overlooked.

Comment: If you need to configure just a few properties, you can use the new @DynamicPropertySource annotation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60941845/8650621

Comment: I used ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, "myPropery", myPropertyValue);

Comment: Here's how I more carefully used `ReflectionTestUtils` to replace an configuration provided API key so I could test for supplying a bad API key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78206625/501113

Answer (score 373, accepted):

You can use `@TestPropertySource` to override values in `application.properties`. From its javadoc:

> test property sources can be used to selectively override properties defined in system and application property sources

For example:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExampleApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class ExampleApplicationTests {

}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Unfortuantly it does not work when used on the ExampleApplication.class so I have to set it on each test class. Is that right?

Comment: It has to go somewhere in the test class's hierarchy, i.e. you could use a common superclass to configure it across a number of different test classes.

Comment: Yes, that would be a proper woraround but as `@PropertySource` is supported on `@Configuration` classes why not also `@TestPropertySource` ;-)  Anyway - as expected, the framework will not let me down and I thank you again for answering the question.

Comment: Also note that `@TestPropertySource` can accept a `properties` argument to overwrite some property inline, such as `@TestPropertySource(properties = "myConf.myProp=valueInTest")`, it's useful in case that you don't want a totally brand new property file.

Comment: You can specify multiple files in an array, and also files on the file system (but remember they might not work on the CI server): `@TestPropertySource(locations={"file:C:/dev/...","classpath:test.properties"})`

Comment: Note, that `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is already deprecated, and you should use `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: It would be nice if a file `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` could be used for unit tests.

Comment: @Stefan It can be used if you make the `test` profile active.

Comment: note: `@TestPropertySource` not load yml file, only support properties file

Comment: But we don't want to have to change source code to modify an application property. Instead, we want to *add a command line argument* or *create another, perhaps temporary, .properties* file and force gradle to use that file.

Comment: @Arthur then you have different requirements. I'd ask a new question if I were you.

Answer (score 116):

Spring Boot automatically loads `src/test/resources/application.properties`, if following annotations are used

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

So, rename `test.properties` to `application.properties` to utilize auto configuration.

> If you **only** need to load the properties file (into the Environment) you can also use the following, as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

[*Update: Overriding certain properties for testing*]

1. Add `src/main/resources/application-test.properties`.
2. Annotate test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

This loads `application.properties` and *then* `application-test.properties` properties into application context for the test case, as per rules defined [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-profile-specific).

Demo - https://github.com/mohnish82/so-spring-boot-testprops

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to have two `application.properties` files on the classpath (one in `src/main/resources` and one in `src/test/resources`). Who guarantees that both will be taken and which one will be taken first?

Comment: @FrVaBe Spring is going to guarantee it! Main profile properties are always loaded. Then during the test phase, test properties are loaded, adding/overriding new/existing properties.

If you don't like keeping two files with same name, then you can add `application-test.properties` in `src/main/resources` and specify `test` as the active profile in the test case.

Comment: Spring does not give a guarantee. The build tool will use the test resources in favour of the main resources during tests. But in case of a test application.properties the main application.properties will be ignored. That is not what I want because the main one contains several useful default values and I only need to override some of them during the test (and I do not want to duplicate the whole file in the test section). See [here](https://twitter.com/snicoll/status/887224501871751168).

Comment: You're correct, only properties defined in `src/test/resources/application.properties` are loaded during the test phase, `src/main/resources/application.properties` is ignored.

Comment: If you do not use profiles so far you do not need a dedicated "test" profile. Just name your test properties `application-default.properties` and they will be considered because you are automatically running the "default" profile (if not declared any other).

Comment: This is incorrect. The file automagically loaded is the default `application.properties`, not the test one. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55297676/1763602

Comment: @Marco Did you try running the referenced GitHub project?

Comment: @Mohnish: the project does not use `src/test/resources`, it uses `src/main/resources`. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297676/junit-test-run-in-eclipse-but-fails-with-gradle-test and my answer

Comment: @Marco Not sure where you're getting confused. But if you put a file named `application.properties` under `src/test/resources`, it is picked up for test cases. However, note that in such a case, _only_ properties defined in that file are available. But as frequently we want _main_ properties, with a few of them overridden for our test case, hence the `ActiveProfile` approach suggestion.

Comment: @Mohnish `if you put a file named application.properties under src/test/resources, it is picked up for test cases` This is not true, I tested it in my application and the default application.properties was loaded instead. I had to use `@TestPropertySource`

Comment: @MarcoSulla You might be missing something in your setup. Anyway, I've provided code to showcase it in `test-props-loading` branch of the demo project. It should serve as a proof! Check it out.

Comment: How to set a specific property value for each junit test method?

Comment: @Grigory Kislin - if you have a code edit to suggest, please suggest it as a comment. `application-test` can be placed under `src/main/resources`, as has been done in the referenced GitHub code sample. It allows users to know that test props can be placed at an alternative location. Also, please don't tag code edits as `grammer`.

Comment: `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class` is deprected use `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class` instead. Worked for me

Comment: For me `src/test/application.properties` works, but `src/main/resources/application-test.properties` is ignored, maybe because I'm using Spring Batch.

Answer (score 69):

You can also use [meta-annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-meta) to externalize the configuration. For example:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DefaultTestAnnotations
public class ExampleApplicationTests { 
   ...
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExampleApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public @interface DefaultTestAnnotations { }
```

Answer (score 66):

Another approach suitable for overriding a few properties in your test, if you are using `@SpringBootTest` annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"propA=valueA", "propB=valueB"})
```

Comment: does `SpringBootTest` load the application.properties file?

Comment: @TuGordoBello yes

Answer (score 25):

If you are like me and you have the same `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`, and you are **wondering** why the `application.properties` in your test folder is **not overriding** the `application.properties` in your main resources, read on...

## Simple explanation:

If you have `application.properties` under `src/main/resources` and the same `application.properties` under `src/test/resources`, which `application.properties` gets picked up, **depends on how you are running your tests**. The folder *structure* `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`, is a Maven architectural convention, so if you run your test like `mvnw test` or even `gradlew test`, the `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` will get picked up, as *test* classpath will precede *main* classpath. But, if you run your test like `Run as JUnit Test` in Eclipse/STS, the `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` will get picked up, as *main* classpath precedes *test* classpath.

You can check it out by opening the **menu bar** `Run > Run Configurations > JUnit > *your_run_configuration* > Click on "Show Command Line"`.

You will see something like this:

> XXXbin\javaw.exe -ea -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
> XXX\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE\project_name\bin\main;
> XXX\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE\project_name\bin\test;

Do you see that *classpath* **xxx\main** comes first, and then **xxx\test**? Right, **it's all about classpath** :-)

*Side-note:
Be mindful that properties overridden in the Launch Configuration(In Spring Tool Suite IDE, for example) takes priority over application.properties.*

## Change the order:

Now, everything is configurable in Spring. You can change the build classpath, so that **xxx\test** comes first, and then **xxx\main**.

Simply go to `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export`, change the build class path order by putting any of the **test** folder first such as:

[image]

And that's it!

## Better solution

A better solution though, when testing, would be to activate the `src/test/resources/application-{profile}.properties` (where `profile` can be test), such as the following in `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

> spring.profiles.active=test

This is neater, and gives you complete control on what profile to activate when doing what.

Comment: I find this approach lacking because defining a profile on your test will remove the option to adjust this on the fly via `-Dspring.profiles.active=...` in CI and other environments which might need other configs that wou might not want to override via `-D` as this becomes very tedious. After all spinning up spring context should only be needed for **integration** tests and those are likely to depend on external resources which are different for the environements they run in.

Comment: Hey @elonderin, thanks for your comment. If there are configurations that are common to all, i plug them in `application.properties`. Thereafter, if i develop on `local` and doing `test`, `spring.profiles.active=local, test`. If i am on pre-prod, it becomes `spring.profiles.active=pre-prod, test`. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Apparently, test/application.properties doesn't override main/application.properties.

Answer (score 18):

### TLDR:

So what I did was to have the standard `src/main/resources/application.properties` and also a `src/test/resources/application-default.properties` where i override some settings for ALL my tests.

### For power-developers:

In order to change/use even more easily different spring profiles, I have a now an `application-default.yaml` that declares the profiles I want to use.
This file is not committed, so that each developer may choose his way of activating profiles and needs (e.g. feature) he/she is working on.

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - local
      - devlocal
      - wip
#      - kafka@docker

---
spring.profiles: wip
# ... overriding properties
```

### Whole Story

I ran into the same problem and was not using profiles either so far. It seemed to be bothersome to have to do it now and remember declaring the profile -- which can be easily forgotten.

The trick is, to leverage that a profile specific `application-<profile>.properties` overrides settings in the general profile. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties.

Comment: Note that as of spring boot 2.4 the power-developer way is deprected, see https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Spring 5.2.5 and Spring Boot 2.2.6 and want to override just a few properties instead of the whole file. You can use the new annotation: @DynamicPropertySource

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ExampleIntegrationTests {

    @Container
    static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.neo4j.uri", neo4j::getBoltUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer. Overriding properties from tests very often needs dynamic values, and just switching to another property file as the other answers won't cut it.

Note: The `@Testcontainers` annotation is not required for this to work.

Comment: This doesn't work when not using Test containers

Answer (score 3):

I think you can also use this:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-test.yml")
```

when custom config locations are configured by using spring.config.additional-location, they are used in addition to the default locations.

The file will have precedence

Please refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more details.

Comment: This worked for me, very well.
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.additional-location=file:/Users/..")

Answer (score 3):

This workes for me:

My Test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-test.yml")
class EngineApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

My versions:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.kubemachine'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
}
```

The only test dependency in my gradle file:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

I also have this in my build.gradle file:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and two properties file:

- src/main/resources/application.yml
- src/test/resources/application-test.yml

And in this setup application-test.yml definitely ONLY overrides the values in application.yml. I don't have to repeat the property values from application.yml in application-test.yml. application-test.yml really extends application.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise we may change the default property configurator name, setting the property `spring.config.name=test` and then having class-path resource 
`src/test/test.properties` our native instance of `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication` will be auto-configured from this separated test.properties, ignoring application properties;

Benefit: auto-configuration of tests;

Drawback: exposing "spring.config.name" property at C.I. layer

ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

> spring.config.name=application # Config file name

Comment: Ignoring `application.properties` is not an option for me as I only want to override _some_ of the original configuration values in the test.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to have a single test that doesn't load the src/main/resources/application.properties and this is it.
Create a file: src/test/resources/empty.properties and add the annotation to the test(s) that should ignore the main properties. @TestPropertySource(properties="spring.config.name=empty")

Comment: How to set a specific property value for each junit test method?

Answer (score 1):

```
I just configured min as the following :

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console


# changing the name of my data base for testing
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:mem:mockedDB
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa



# in testing i don`t need to know the port

#Feature that determines what happens when no accessors are found for a type
#(and there are no annotations to indicate it is meant to be serialized).
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

## Setup

Using

- properties declared with `.yaml` file-ending
- Spring-Boot 2.7
- and multiple .yaml files in the classpath

## Problem

I noticed that the precedence of `@TestPropertySource(locations)` was not applied as it would be with `.properties` files.

The problem I was having was, that Spring kept loading all `.yaml` properties (especially those from production) and **overriding** the properties meant for the tests with the values specified for prod. (*sigh*)

## Solution

We come up with the workaround of overwriting the config-scraping mechanism by specifying just my `application-test.yaml` as the only properties used like so:

```yaml
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.location=classpath:/application-test.yaml")
```

## Alternative solution

As mentioned above: with `.properties` files everything works as expected.

Another solution would be to transpile the `.yaml` to `.properties`.

Here is a handy online converter: https://mageddo.com/tools/yaml-converter (note its inability to cope with comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spring.factories file in src/test/resources/META-INF and a EnvironmentPostProcessor Implementation class in src/test/java.
`spring.factories` like

```
# Environment Post Processors
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
com.example.test.YourTestPropertiesConfig
```

`YourTestPropertiesConfig.java` like

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class YourTestPropertiesConfig implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private static final Map<String, Object> testProperties = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Set<String> testPropertiesFile = new HashSet<>();

    static {
    //Add the properties you need to take effect globally in the test directly here.
        testProperties.put("spring.jackson.time-zone", "GMT");
        testPropertiesFile.add("classpath:test.properties");
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("TestProperties", testProperties));
        for (String location : testPropertiesFile) {
            try {
                environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(location));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addProperty(String key, Object value) {
        testProperties.put(key, value);
    }

    public static void addProperty(String location) {
        testPropertiesFile.add(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want/have to use `System.setProperties(...)` then use a Junit extension and annotate the test class:

```
...
@ExtendWith(MyBeforeAllCallback.class)
public SomeTestClass ...
```

and use the constructor of the callback to set the system properties.

```
public MyBeforeAllCallback implements BeforeAllCallback {
    public MyBeforeAllCallback() {
        // wicket 9 workaround for java 17 / cglib issue.
        System.setProperty("wicket.ioc.useByteBuddy", "true");
        // ... whatever you want ...
        System.setProperty("whatever", "you need it badly");
    }
    void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        // ... empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a application.properties file in src/test/resources where your JUnits are written.

Comment: How does this help? ^^

Comment: This is what he DOESN'T wants...

Comment: Thanks I had made application-test.properties in test/resources folder - renamed it to application.properties and it worked