# @TestPropertySource with dynamic properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am using @TestPropertySource to overwrite application.yml properties in my integration test for a spring boot app.

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "repository.file.path=src/test/resources/x" })
```

I was wondering if there was some way to make the property VALUE dynamic. Something like this:

```
 @TestPropertySource(properties = { "repository.file.path=PropertyValueProvider.class" })
```

Your feedback is appreciated. In my case the property value is system specific that should be generated upon the test run.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`@TestPropertySource` only provides *declarative* mechanisms for configuring `PropertySource`s. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-testpropertysource) in Spring Reference Manual.

If you need programmatic support for adding a `PropertySource` to the `Environment`, you should implement an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which can be registered via `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ...)`. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-initializers) in Spring Reference Manual.

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: I found [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/8dd1354d82be9bae236e3e8804c82f0987c42729/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/redis/DataRedisTestIntegrationTests.java#L93) to show how it is done in practice.

Comment: @barfuin - This looks like exactly what i need...except I'm using Boot v1.5 and that example uses features (TestPropertyValues) introduced in 2.0. Don't suppose anyone would have any other examples?

Comment: In Spring Boot 1.5.x you can use the `properties` attribute of `@SpringBootTest`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.21.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#properties--

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this with the `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation in Spring Boot 5.2. This enables you to set the property value programmatically (dynamically).

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24540

Add this to your integration test class:

```java
@DynamicPropertySource
static void dynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
  registry.add("my.property", () -> {
       // some logic to get your property dynamically
   });
}
```

Comment: How would you do if you want to test with 2 or more values in `my.property`?

Answer (score 1):

I did this thanks to [Sam Brannen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013353/1089967)

Here's the sample code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfiguration.class }, initializers = { MyInitializer.class })
public class MyContextConfiguration {
    public static class MyInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            String userNameLower = System.getProperty("user.name").toLowerCase();
            Map<String, Object> dynamicProperties = Map.of("user.name.lower", userNameLower);
            MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("dynamic", dynamicProperties);
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:my-static.properties") // properties in this file can reference ${user.name.lower}
    public static class MyConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MyBean myBean(@Value("${user.name.lower}") String userNameLower) {
            return new MyBean(userNameLower);
        }
    }
}
```