# Will @TestPropertySource honor SPEL or values from other properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm wondering if the `@TestPropertySource` will honor SpEL or will at least allow a property to substitute values from another property.

It's a similar question to  [@TestPropertySource with dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855874/testpropertysource-with-dynamic-properties)

Assuming the properties I'm referring to exist in one of the files in the `locations` attribute...

For example if I'd like to do something like:

```
@TestPropertySource(
    locations = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:database.properties"},
    properties = {"newPortNum = #{1 + Integer.parseInt(${myapp.web.server.port.ssl})}})
```

Or this:

```
@TestPropertySource(
    locations = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:database.properties"},
    properties = {"outputFile = ${outputDir}/foo.txt"})
```

Do I need to implement a `TestExecutionListener` or `@BootstrapWith` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from the Javadoc for `@TestPropertySource.locations()`:

> Property placeholders in paths (i.e., `${...}`) will be resolved against the `Environment`.

... that means: against anything already added to the `Environment`.

SpEL expressions, on the other hand, are not supported.

If you need programmatic support for adding a `PropertySource` to the `Environment`, you should implement an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which can be registered via `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ...)`.

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: I've confirmed that both your suggestions work.  Thanks