# Wiremock stubFor returns SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock, spring-cloud-feign

I need to mock feign client and I tried to use Wiremock as exemplified at [How to write integration tests with spring-cloud-netflix and feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465990/how-to-write-integration-tests-with-spring-cloud-netflix-and-feign)

However I got the following error when calling `stubFor`

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.safelyExecuteRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:473)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.executeRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:454)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.addStubMapping(HttpAdminClient.java:131)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:298)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:293)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.givenThat(WireMock.java:104)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.java:108)
    at com.example.app.controller.MyIntegrityTest.whenFlagSuccess_thenShouldReturnAllPayments(MyIntegrityTest.java:325)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:60)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:70)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

and here is the code of `MyIntegrationTest.java`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {MyAppTests.class, com.example.app.ContextConfiguration.class},
        properties = {"feign.hystrix.enabled=true"}
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyIntegrityTest.LocalRibbonClientConfiguration.class})
public class MyIntegrityTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static WireMockClassRule wiremock = new WireMockClassRule(
            wireMockConfig().dynamicPort());
    @Rule public WireMockClassRule instanceRule = wiremock;

    @TestConfiguration
        public static class LocalRibbonClientConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
            System.out.println("wiremock.port()" + wiremock.port());
            return new StaticServerList<>(new Server("localhost", wiremock.port()));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
       stubFor(WireMock.post(anyUrl())
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .withBody("{}")
                )
        );
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If the `stubfor` method results in a Connection reset, it means that something is listening on your host on that specific port already. You can see that during stubbing it uses an `HttpAdminClient` to check that port and fires a request towards it. That pre-flight request results in that Connection reset.