# Spring Boot - How to set or override properties defined in application.yml via a custom extension class that implements BeforeAllCallback?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit

I have an extension class that implements `BeforeAllCallback` to set a random port like this.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext
import java.net.ServerSocket

class CustomExtension : org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback {
    var port: Int? = null

    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        port = getRandomPort()
    }
    
    private fun getRandomPort(): Int {
        ServerSocket(0).use { 
            serverSocket -> return serverSocket.localPort 
        }
    }

}
```

Also, I have a property defined in `src/test/resources/application.yml` like this.

```
app:
  random-port: 8765
```

This property is used by this configuration class.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
data class PortProperty(
    val randomPort: Int
)
```

### Question

How can I override that hard corded `app.random-port` when running my tests from the `CustomExtension` class? The idea is so that my `PortProperty` gets the right value and not the hard coded one.

My test framework is `JUnit5`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(CustomExtension::class)
class RandomPortTest {
}
```

### Edit

The use case is actually to start a local dynamo db using the AWS DynamoDBLocal library for the test classes.

Comment: I don't think you want an extension if you only need to override the port. Look at `DynamicPropertySource` or  `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058489/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test-with
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management

Comment: The use case is actually to start a local dynamo db using the AWS DynamoDBLocal library, that is why I want it to be an extension so I can do the same for each test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `app.random-port` system property in the `beforeAll` method. As system properties have [higher priority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) than properties files, the port value from the application.yml will get overridden:

```kotlin
override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
    port = getRandomPort()
    System.setProperty("app.random-port", port?.toString())
}
```