# Spring Test ActiveProfiles is not reading the properties from the test properties file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, application.properties, spring-profiles

I have my custom properties defined in application.properties file located in src/main/resources folder. I want to add test cases for my application hence I added application-integration.properties in the src/test/resources folder as mentioned [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties#springProfile). The test case is added as below

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
public class ServiceATest {

    @Value("${app.api.url}")
    private String apiUrl;

    @Test
    public void testService() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(apiUrl);
    }
}
```

The above test case fails. I do not understand why the properties are not read from application-integration.properties and nor from application.properties. The latter is not expected though still just for the understanding. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the problem occur - in Eclipse, on the command line with 'mvn'?

Comment: On running the test class from Intellij Community Edition

Comment: Did you define some kind of configuration in Intellij using `-Dspring.profiles.active=xxx`? Do the test fail using mvn on the command line, too?

Comment: I tried setting an environment variable when executing the above test class as `-Dspring.profiles.active=integration` but the test case still failed. Maven test run is taking time since there are other test classes that are failing. will check and revert back

Comment: Perhaps your integration config doesn’t contain all the properties. If it doesn’t it will grab them from your generic application.properties

Comment: @DanielJacob - the problem is certainly to do with test config. It doesn't seem to be reading any properties files