# Configure specific in memory database for testing purpose in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

How do I configure my *Spring Boot* application so that when I run *unit tests* it will use **in-memory** database such as `H2`/`HSQL` but when I run *Spring Boot* application it will use production database `PostgreSQL`/`MySQL` ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Spring profiles can be used for this. This would be a specific way:

Have environment specific properties files:

**application.properties**:

```
spring.profiles.active: dev
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database: MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update

spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username: username
spring.datasource.password: password
```

**application-test.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database: HSQL
```

Have both *MySQL* and *H2* drivers in `pom.xml`, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Last but not the least, annotate Test classes with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

Comment: The `dev` profile seems weird to me. Isn't that supposed to be the "production" one? In this case, just put that info in `application.properties`, no need for `spring.profiles.active` either.

Comment: I have a separate `prod` profile. If we put the `dev` info in *application.properties*, wouldn't that info leak to the `test` profile?

Comment: All I am saying is that you're not answering the question. Dev/test is confusing in your answer. I'd expect a prod profile and then a test profile but not a "Dev" one. You could just as well have a "prod" profile with the production and leave the default for the test. Since Spring Boot does not find any specific information it'll use the embedded container.

Comment: Do I put application-test.properties on src/main/resources ?
My tests unfortunately still pointing to the production database

Comment: Yes, you should be putting that right beside application.properties. Where have you put these?

Comment: Isn't the use of colons for yml files? Should that be `=` instead?

Comment: @Sanjay is the best

Answer (score 46):

Another approach is to add the annotation `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` to you test class.
My tests usually look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // Tests...
    }
}
```

Note that the embedded database dependency needs to be added in the pom.xml file.
For embedded database this annotation is not necessary it will work even if only the dependency is added in pom file.

Comment: This is the best approach. No need to configure anything through properties, because you need H2 only in testing scenario.

Answer (score 10):

With @SpringBootTest magic, you just need to do following two changes.

1. Add 'h2' test dependency in pom.xml

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
>     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Use @[AutoConfigureTestDatabase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html)

> ```
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> @SpringBootTest(classes = MySpringBootApplication.class)
> @AutoConfigureTestDatabase
> public class SpringBootTest{
>
>     @Autowired
>     private RequestRepository requestRepository;
> }
> ```

Now all the spring jpa bean/repositories used in test will use h2 as backing database.

> 2019-04-26 13:13:34.198  INFO 28627 --- [           main]
> beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource'
> DataSource bean with embedded version
>
> 2019-04-26 13:13:34.199  INFO 28627 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition
> for bean 'dataSource'
>
> 2019-04-26 13:13:36.194  INFO 28627 --- [           main]
> o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database:
> url='jdbc:h2:mem:2784768e-f053-4bb3-ab88-edda34956893;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false',
> username='sa'

Note: I still have 'spring-jpa' properties defined in 'application.properties' and I don't use any profiles. @[AutoConfigureTestDatabase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html) will override existing jpa configurations with test defaults AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.

Answer (score 8):

Simplest solution:

1) in src/main/resources have application.properties (production config):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and application-test.properties with HSQL config like:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.database = HSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:hsqldb:mem:scratchdb
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
```

2) Add HSQL dependency in pom.xml if you don't have it already.

3) Annotate your test class with @ActiveProfiles("test").

Worked like charm in my case.

Comment: Hey, how do you set up hsql itself?

Comment: Hi @AlexBondar. You can use the sample before it but you can use replace=Replace.NONE inside AutoConfigureTestDatabase

Comment: spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver should be spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Answer (score 6):

@Sanjay has one way to put it but I find it confusing. You could just as well have only a `production` profile that you enable when you're in production, something like:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username: username
spring.datasource.password: password
```

And don't specify anything else. If you add an embedded database in `test` scope, it will be available in your tests. If you run your tests with the default profile (no customization whatsoever), it won't find any database information (since these are stored in the `production` profile). In that case, it will try to find an embedded database and start it for you. If you need more customization for some reason, you can have a `application-test.properties` for those (you'll need to add `ActiveProfiles("test")` to your test(s).

Comment: In my scenarios, I would have a MySQL database in my PC, which would be used when running the app locally while developing. That's why I thought we needed a `dev` profile to run the app, and a `test` profile to run the tests through my IDE. Any simplification could be done in this case?

Comment: Just add `application-dev.properties` with your MySQL DB and enable the `dev` profile when you run the app from your IDE.

Comment: Okay, what I understand then is that my answer above looks suiting this case, except that I could have skipped having the `test` profile and the `@ActiveProfile` if the `test` profile had nothing except just the DB. Let me know if this sounds wrong.

Comment: I don't think your answer suits this case. Nobody asked for a `dev` profile; I am not denying it is useful but that's not what the question is all about.  The `dev` profile is always enabled in your answer. That feels wrong as well. Anyway, no need to discuss it any further IMO :) -

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution if building with `maven`: just place an `application.properties` file under `src/test/resources` and edit as appropriate for testing.

The Spring (Boot) Profile mechanism is a pretty powerful tool that, in scope, goes way beyond "swapping settings between test time and run time". Although, clearly, as demonstrated, it can do that also :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution enables common settings for develop and test.  Is based on this solution:
[Override default Spring-Boot application.properties settings in Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test)

1. **application.properties** in src/main/resources/application.properties

```
    #common settings for DEVELOPMENT and TEST:
    ......
    ......

    ## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=somepassword

    # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC

    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

2. **test.properties** (src/main/resources/application.properties) which **overrides and adds** properties in application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.h2.console.enabled=false
```

3. settings in **pom.xml** for H2 and Postgre databases

```
      <!-- h2 -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      </dependency>

    <!-- postgress -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

4. In **test class**:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
    public class ModelTest { 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a multi-module Gradle SpringBootApplication with below Modules

1. **employeemanagerApp** - Where my SpringApplication main class
2. **employeemanagerIntTests** - Where i have my cucumber tests

My requirement was to use MySQL DB when the application boots up and H2 during my Cucumber Integration testing

**Solution:** In my employeemanagerApp module, src/main/resources i placed the application.properties with below content

```
#My SQL Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanager
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And in the Integration Test Module (employeemanagerIntTests) src/**test**/resources I placed the application.properties with below content

```
#H2 In-Memory DB Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2://mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

And in my Step Definition Class i added only these annotations

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplicationMainClass.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

In the build.gradle file i added H2 dependency

```
testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
```

So when I ran my tests, H2 was active and all tests with Create, Update, Read and Delete were successful

Answer (score 0):

Some ppl told that best approach is using @AutoConfigureTestDatabase , but this will not work if you are using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate , that was my case.

If you use this, @AutoConfigureTestDatabase will only create the connection, but will still miss the tables.

Due for this the best ansewer was from [@Sanjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075051/sanjay) , using the application-test.properties.

In this case, is easy to configure the new database and override the configuration validate to update:

```
spring.jpa.database: HSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Doing this and importing in your test class:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UserRepositoryTests {
    ...
}
```

It will finally work.

PS: Just like Sanjay said in accepted ansewer, you will need to add the dependency in your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```