# NullPointerException while running unit test against Postgres database with Unitils

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, junit, unitils

I have the following table (migration):

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: me
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: person
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: int
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: first_name
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: last_name
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
  - changeSet:
      id: 2
      author: me
      changes:
        - insert:
            tableName: person
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: first_name
                  value: First
              - column:
                  name: last_name
                  value: Last
```

And the following DAO:

```
public interface HelloDao {
    @SqlQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM person"
    )
    @Mapper(PersonMapper.class)
    Person getPerson();
}
```

With the following entities + mapper:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

-

```
public class PersonMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Person> {
    public Person map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        return new Person(r.getString("first_name"), r.getString("last_name"));
    }
}
```

I'm using junit and unitils to write a unit test for this Dao. I have the `unitils.properties` file set up like so:

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
database.dialect=postgresql
database.userName=<username>
database.password=<password>
database.schemaNames=public
```

Just for clarity, this my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.main.show-banner=false
logging.level.jdbc=OFF
logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=DEBUG
logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=<username> 
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Here is my test:

```
@Transactional(TransactionMode.ROLLBACK)
@RunWith(UnitilsBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class HelloDaoTest {
    @TestDataSource
    DataSource dataSource;

    private DBI dbi;
    private HelloDao helloDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        dbi = new DBI(dataSource);
        helloDao = dbi.onDemand(HelloDao.class);
    }

    @Test
    @DataSet("HelloDaoTest.testSet.xml")
    public void helloDao() throws Exception {
        Person p = helloDao.getPerson();
        assertEquals("First", p.getFirstName());
    }

}
```

And my fixture (`HelloDaoTest.testSet.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <dataset>
        <person
            first_name="First"
            last_name="Last"
        />
    </dataset>
```

and the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.experiment.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>testspringbootproj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring Boot Blank Project (from https://github.com/making/spring-boot-blank)</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.experiment.springboot.App</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.14.8</lombok.version>
        <log4jdbc.log4j2.version>1.16</log4jdbc.log4j2.version>
        <rest.assured.version>2.3.3</rest.assured.version>
        <jdbi.version>2.78</jdbi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest.assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
            <version>${log4jdbc.log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
            <artifactId>unitils-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-loaded.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:820)
    at org.unitils.database.transaction.impl.DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.rollback(DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.java:157)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.rollbackTransaction(DatabaseModule.java:425)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.endTransactionForTestMethod(DatabaseModule.java:390)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule$DatabaseTestListener.afterTestTearDown(DatabaseModule.java:486)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.afterTestTearDown(Unitils.java:315)
    at org.unitils.core.junit.AfterTestTearDownStatement.evaluate(AfterTestTearDownStatement.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.unitils.core.junit.BeforeTestClassStatement.evaluate(BeforeTestClassStatement.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

It looks like the test code is not even reached. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not an expert on any of these techs, but if you look at the stack trace it looks as if the tests expect there to be some kind of transaction manager in a complete spring context, but that doesn't get set up (no spring junit runner).

Comment: please look at the second line of the test `@RunWith(UnitilsBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: Well, did you set up a Spring Application Context as described in http://unitils.sourceforge.net/tutorial-spring.html ?

Comment: yes i did this @TassosBassoukos

Answer (score 3):

You do have two database implementations in your pom.xml, without specifying scopes. Spring is not able to guess which one shall be the right one, hence an exception.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
```

Most likely this will help you further: [Configure specific in memory database for testing purpose in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001391/configure-specific-in-memory-database-for-testing-purpose-in-spring)

Answer (score 2):

I can't add a comment because of <50 rep. I thought maybe this would be useful.

[Rollback transaction after @Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test)

It isn't using Unitils, but does seem to be the behavior that you are looking for. Unitils seems to have been last updated back in 2011 (and my suspicion is that is where your problem lies) so it might be worth junking it.