# Use in-memory db to write tests for Rest controllers

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I'm writing a test for a Spring boot Rest controller. This rest controller writes some values to the db.

I want to use in-memory database which Spring provides for this test. According to [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) I have to annotate the test class with `@DataJpaTest`, which causes this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Further down in the error stack trace I see the following exception was thrown:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoconfigureTestDatabase.`

This is the test class which I'm working on:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DataJpaTest
public class AuthenticationControllerFTest {

    @Autowired 
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {

        String exampleUserInfo = "{\"name\":\"Salam12333\",\"username\":\"test@test1.com\",\"password\":\"Salam12345\"}";
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/signup")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(exampleUserInfo)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        int status = response.getStatus();
        Assert.assertEquals("http response status is wrong", 200, status);
    }
}
```

What is causing this error ?

**Edit 1**
This is the content of my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.username = hello
spring.datasource.password = hello
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject?useSSL=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:tomcat.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password = hello
server.ssl.key-password = hello
server.ssl.enabled = true
server.ssl.key-alias=myproject
```

**Edit 2**

I added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I created `application-test.properties` with the following content:

```
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

1. What is the username and passowrd ? Where should I set them ?
2. I also added `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to the test class, when I run the test I get an error which includes this line :

`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

Comment: "If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoconfigureTestDatabase". So, did you put an embedded database on the classpath?

Comment: I add my `application.properties` file content to the original post.

Comment: application.properties doesn't affect classpath. You need to add h2 or hsqldb to your pom.xml.

Comment: I added it, please see Edit 2.

Comment: `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` -- h2 is not hsqldb. See answer below .. go slowly and carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you annotate class with `@SpringBootApplication`, which enables auto-configuration and you have `H2` dependency on classpath(see below) `Spring Boot` will see `H2` in-memory database dependency and it will create `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation. Default connection URL is `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` and the default username and password are: username: sa and password: empty.

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:tesdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=

    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
    spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

    spring.jpa.show-sql = true
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true // if you need console
```

H2 Dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency> // If you need h2 web console 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

You can gain access to h2 console for management `http://localhost:8080/h2-console`

Comment: Are the values for the `username` and `password` default ? if not, where should I set them ? Why is the scope `runtime` and not `test` ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I have updated my answer,
Credentials are default, you can change them in h2 console, added description to my answer. Not sure about scope - runtime works fine for me. You can change for test.

Answer (score 3):

For Testing REST service with in-memory DB, you need to following things:

1.  Add h2 dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

2. Define h2 configuration in application.properties or application.yaml

```
spring.jpa.database = h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

3. Annotate you test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Complete code will be like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AuthenticationControllerFTest {

    @Autowired 
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {

        String exampleUserInfo = "{\"name\":\"Salam12333\",\"username\":\"test@test1.com\",\"password\":\"Salam12345\"}";
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/signup")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(exampleUserInfo)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        int status = response.getStatus();
        Assert.assertEquals("http response status is wrong", 200, status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove both annotations @AutoConfigureMockMvc and @DataJpaTest. You are trying to test the complete applciation, so need the @SpringBootTest annotation.  @DataJpaTest is only needed if you want to test only the data apllication slice. Have a look at this: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

Comment: But I don't want to use the actual db. I want to use in-memory db.

Comment: When I remove both annotations, I get this error: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mockMvc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot we do not require to add any thing additional for in memory database configuration except for jar file on class path and application property file (`application.properties`) on the class path (`src/test/resources` if maven is used) rest of the things will be taken care by spring boot (beauty of boot).

Another option is to provide profile specific properties file on the class path `src/amin/resources` (for example `application-test.properties`)

Both of the file are valid for test configurations

Sample configuration for property file is given below (consider HSQL DB jar on class path):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.database = HSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:scratchdb
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

See also [Configure specific in memory database for testing purpose in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001391/configure-specific-in-memory-database-for-testing-purpose-in-spring)

Comment: And I assume that I have to configure hsqldb first, right ?

Comment: Is there a way to set `username`, `password` and create `testdb` in Java ?

Comment: The database is in memory ... what do you mean create `testdb`? Hibernate will create the tables from your entities on startup. If you want to preload it with values you have to use a SQL script. If you have other questions please search SO or ask a new question.

Comment: My question is regarding your answer. Where does the values for `username` and `password` come from ? from my understanding it tries to connect to `testdb` using values provided for properties `username` and `password`.

Comment: They are hardcoded for hsqldb. I think any database name will do, see [Chapter 1. Running and Using HyperSQL](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#N10231).

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you can use below in-memory db with integration test -

This will also help if you are using json[b](though it is in DB2 but some ops like inserting/updating not support with our code) datatype or any other field that is not present in DB2 (compatibility issue).

Then refer this [TestContainer - Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259759/410439)

Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

XyzIT.java

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers

mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
@Test
void test(){
        var mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/opportunities/process")
                .header("emailId", "ravi.parekh@xyz.com")
                .header("Authorization", "authorization")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json").content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(opportunity))).andReturn();

}
```

Application-test.yml

```
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    schema: classpath*:schema-h2.sql  #initial sql script to createDB
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.9:///
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        default_schema: public
    show-sql: true
```