# Spring Boot testing with H2 - Table "OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN" not found

Tags: spring-boot, junit, h2

I'm thinking I need to setup the db testing environment (e.g. create tables, seed users so that token can be issued with credentials) before I can run tests but not sure how to.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {

    // ...

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
          .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    private String obtainAccessToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("client_id", CLIENTID);
        params.add("grant_type", CLIENTPASSWORD);
        params.add("username", username);
        params.add("password", password);

        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
            .params(params)
            .with(httpBasic(CLIENTID, CLIENTPASSWORD))
            .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

        String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenNoToken_whenGetAllUsers_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(
            get("/users")
            ).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    public void givenToken_whenGetAllUsers_thenOk() throws Exception {
        String accessToken = obtainAccessToken("martyn", "secret");
        mockMvc.perform(
            get("/users")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    // ...
```

Here is a typical Entity for this app:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8507204786382662588L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id") // cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true
    private List<Fund> funds;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    // standard getters and setters

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Fund> getFunds() {
        return funds;
    }
}
```

But also, as the error indicates, I'd need to generate these oauth* tables too.

Here is my src/test/resources/application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

So I guess I want to generate the tables (entities, and oauth*) in the H2 database prior to running tests and populate with a single user(?) but can't seem to figure how this is done in Spring Boot. Or should I not be hitting any database and mocking JDBC altogether? Could someone point me in the correct direction as to how to prepare a test environment here? I'm at a bit of a loss.

UPDATE

Here is how dataSource is configured:

```
@Configuration
public class JDBCTokenConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    // @Bean
    // public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    //     return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    // }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have a look at flyway (https://flywaydb.org) or Liquibase (https://www.liquibase.org). Both allow automated migrations, which will also trigger in development environments.

Comment: Thanks for the response. These tables are not my own though, they belong to Spring Security for managing tokens. So I'm not comfortable writing migrations for these tables, but I get where you're coming from. Anyway I'm going to post a revision of this that differs slightly and is a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good thing to reach your in memory database without mocking. Honestly, you will need more time to configure rather than creating the correct schema needed for your database.

Using `Spring-boot`, it is very easy to configure to test your application:

1. Declare using `spring-boot-starter-jpa`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2. Add the in memory DB for your tests

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

3. Delete your `spring.datasource` properties in `application.properties`

Thanks to `@SpringBootApplication`, the datasource will be automatically configured to connect to your H2 in memory database.

4. Create the SQL schema
   By default, `spring-boot-starter-jpa` configures automatically the datasource to execute scripts `classpath:/schema.sql` and if you need also, `classpath:/data.sql`.
   Create a `schema.sql` in `src/test/resources`, and create the tables (copy the following content, I think this is what you need: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) (I am not sure for this, maybe `hibernate` creates your schema on his own).
   Create your schema in `src/test/resources/schema.sql` and seed the users in `src/test/resources/data.sql`

Check also the spring documentation to know how you can configure hibernate :

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-properties
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Now I understand, which is everybody, that you need to have your configuration different dependending on your environment. The best to do that is to rely on profiles.

In your situation, you have a `prod` profile, and a `test` profile.

Declare the profile and keep your `spring.datasource` properties in your `src/test/resources/application.properties` (the easier in your case I think)

I suggest you to read this [Configure specific in memory database for testing purpose in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001391/configure-specific-in-memory-database-for-testing-purpose-in-spring), and let me know if you have troubles configuring your environment.

With this, you will need to:

- Add an annotation at the top of your Test class `@ActiveProfiles('test')`
- Restore the `spring.datasource` properties you previously deleted an put them in `src/test/resources/application-test.properties`

Let me know

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was missing `<scope>test</scope>` from the pom file for H2, so I've added that. I've removed everything from src/test/resources/application.properties file, however, I'm now seeing the following error - `Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.url' in value "${spring.datasource.url}"` - but I do still need this property for non-test environments. Btw I've updated my post to show where this is defined.

Comment: Could you provide your POM as well ? When using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` or `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`, you don’t need to configure a Datasource yourself. It will be provided, and you can use this « provided » Datasource like any other regular bean