# Spring Batch - In Memory

Tags: spring-batch

How to use in-memory database for spring batch instead of database?

Any good reference is appreciable. Looking for code snippet.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-batch-h2-database. If you still need a separate database connection for your readers/writers, you'll need to configure multiple datasources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure specific in memory database for testing purpose in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001391/configure-specific-in-memory-database-for-testing-purpose-in-spring)