# Spring Boot integration tests doesn't read properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4, properties-file

I would like to create integration test in which Spring Boot will read a value from .properties file using **@Value** annotation.
But every time I'm running test my assertion fails because Spring is unable to read the value:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :works!
Actual   :${test}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebTests.ConfigurationClass.class, WebTests.ClassToTest.class})
public class WebTests {
    @Configuration
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    static class ConfigurationClass {}

    @Component
    static class ClassToTest{
        @Value("${test}")
        private String test;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ClassToTest config;

    @Test
    public void testTransferService() {
        Assert.assertEquals(config.test, "works!");
    }
}
```

application-test.properties under src/main/resource package contains:

```
test=works!
```

What can be the reason of that behavior and how can I fix it?
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: What does `ClassToTest` look like? Have you got `@SpringBootTest` anywhere? It would guess that your tests aren't running as a Spring Boot test so application properties isn't being loaded. If that was happening, setting the active profile to `test` should have been sufficient to get `application-test.properties` to load

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should  load the application-test.properties using @PropertySource or @TestPropertySource

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebTests.ConfigurationClass.class, WebTests.ClassToTest.class})
public class WebTests {

}
```

for more info: Look into this [Override default Spring-Boot application.properties settings in Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test)

Answer (score 5):

Besides the above marked correct answer, there is another nature way to load application-test.properties: Set your test run "profile" to "test".

Mark your test cases with:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

application-xxxx.properties is a naming convention for properties of different "profile".

This file application-xxxx.properties should be placed in src/main/resources folder.

"Profile" is also useful in bean configuration.

Comment: application-test.properties should be in `src/test/resources` folder