# Read a Map with Spring @ConfigurationProperties in test

Tags: java, spring, junit

Following a advice from [Spring Boot integration tests doesn't read properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396982/spring-boot-integration-tests-doesnt-read-properties-files) I created the following code, with the intention of reading a map from properties in my JUnit test.
(I am using yml format, and using @ConfigurationProperties instead of @Value)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.yml")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PropertiesTest.ConfigurationClass.class, PropertiesTest.ClassToTest.class})
public class PropertiesTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    static class ConfigurationClass {
    }


    @ConfigurationProperties
    static class ClassToTest {
        private String test;

        private Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();

        public String getTest() {
            return test;
        }

        public void setTest(String test) {
            this.test = test;
        }

        public Map<String, Object> getMyMap() {
            return myMap;
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private ClassToTest config;


    @Test
    public void testStringConfig() {
        Assert.assertEquals(config.test, "works!");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapConfig() {
        Assert.assertEquals(config.myMap.size(), 1);
    }

}
```

My test configuration (in application-test.yml):

```
test: works!
myMap:
  aKey: aVal
  aKey2: aVal2
```

Strangely, the String "works!" is successfully read from the config file, but the map is not populated.

What am I missing?

Note: adding a map setter causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'target' on field 'myMap': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.target.myMap,typeMismatch.myMap,typeMismatch.java.util.Map,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.myMap,myMap]; arguments []; default message [myMap]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'myMap'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'myMap': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.checkForBindingErrors(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:359)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:330)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: you don't have setter for your map. that is the reason it is not working. Spring calls setters to populate the values

Comment: The similar bean is successfully created in the full application without a setter (map values can be added without setting the entire map). Adding the setter in test ends in exception - added stack trace in question

Comment: I guess `String, Object` isn't a good fit. Did you tried `<String, String>` just for the case it doesn't know how to deserialize aVal2 to `Object`?

Comment: No. For ConfigurationProperties to work, you need a setter. without that it doesn't work. It can be verified easily, just remove the setter for test and see if that works. I am sure it does not.  Now coming to the exception when you add a setter,  I think this is a bug in Databinder.  I Changed value type to String, still doesn't work. Remove initialization of map, still didn't work. But If I put the same in application.properties file It works. It is strange. You should raise a issue on github

Comment: I checked it at the docs and verified it on my computer: You are right. Without a setter, it won't work this way. But this one stays working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28764090/4068240 To be honest, I don't really get why.

Comment: while regular application runs. The problem is only in test class as @Lesiak already mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some wonderful time with a debugger, 
I believe that this is a bug / missing feature in `TestPropertySourceUtils.addPropertiesFilesToEnvironment()`:

```
try {
    for (String location : locations) {
        String resolvedLocation = environment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(location);
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resolvedLocation);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(resource));
    }
}
```

`ResourcePropertySource` can only deal with `.properties` files and not `.yml`.
In regular app, `YamlPropertySourceLoader` registered and can deal with `.yml`.

As a note:
`TestPropertySourceUtils.addPropertiesFilesToEnvironment()` is called by:

```
org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.prepareContext()
```

(inherited from `AbstractContextLoader`)

`DelegatingSmartContextLoader` is the default context loader you receive if no loader is specified in `@ContextConfiguration`.
(in fact `@ContextConfiguration` specifies an interface, but `AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.resolveContextLoader()` changes it to a concrete class)

To resolve the problem, I changed my configuration to `application-test.properties`
and used that file in my test.

```
test=works!
myMap.aKey: aVal
```

Another comment: the setter on the map is NOT needed:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

> To bind to properties like that using the Spring DataBinder utilities
>   (which is what @ConfigurationProperties does) you need to have a
>   property in the target bean of type java.util.List (or Set) and you
>   either need to provide a setter, or initialize it with a mutable
>   value, e.g. this will bind to the properties above

Comment: `@TestPropertySource` and `@PropertySource` do not support yaml files.