# Spring boot - test properties overriden with prod properties

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5

My test properties are overriden with those placed in production properties.
At the very beggining I had both named `application.yml` but it didn't work, so I have changed like told in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test) to `application-test.yml` and use profile.
Now it looks like bellow (kotlin):

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [InvalidPropertiesApplication::class])
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application.yml"])
class InvalidPropertiesApplicationTests {
    @Test
    fun contextLoads(@Autowired users: Users) {
        assertEquals("TEST", users.file)
    }
}
```

in `src/main/resources/application.yml` I have only set this property 
 to `PRODUCTION`, in `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` to `TEST`.

And this test fails.
Full example can be found [at github](https://github.com/Azbesciak/SpringInvalidConfiguration)

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties loaded with `@TestPropertySource` have a higher precedence than all other property sources in your example. And `"classpath:application.yml"` refers to `src/main/resources/application.yml`.

Order: @TestPropertySource > application-{profile}.properties/yaml > application.properties/yaml

See also the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: Thx, I have seen this and made some changes, but no dif... However, now it helped, maybe cache or smth.

Comment: But if I had specified `@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application.yml"])` and both property files were named `application.yml`, shouldn't the one from `test` be resolved?