# Junit test run in Eclipse but fails with `gradle test`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I'm using Spring Boot 2 and I'm trying to do an integration test.
I configured a custom `application.properties` this way:

```
@TestPropertySource(
    locations = "classpath:###/$$$/application-integrationtest.properties"
)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "###.$$$" })
```

File is under `src/test/java/###/$$$/application-integrationtest.properties`

Running Junit under Eclipse works fine, but if I try `gradle test`, I get:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [###/$$$/application-integrationtest.properties] cannot be opened
>   because it does not exist

What's the deal?

Comment: properties files don't go to src/test/java. That's for **java** source files. They go to src/test/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [JB Nizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297676/junit-test-run-in-eclipse-but-fails-with-gradle-test#comment97324530_55297676) I put my property file under `src/test/resources` and added the folder to the build path in Eclipse.