# Integration testing for spring cloud stream, how to ensure application resources are not used

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to do some integration testing for my cloud streaming application. One of the main issues I'm observing so far is that the TestChannelBinderConfiguration keeps picking up the configuration specified in `src/main/java/resources/application.yml` instead of keeping it as blank (since there is no config file in `/src/test/resources/`).

If I delete the `application.yml` file or remove all spring-cloud-stream related configuration, the test passes. How can I ensure that the TestChannelBinderConfiguration does not pick up `application.yml` file.

```
  @Test
  public void echoTransformTest() {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(
              TestChannelBinderConfiguration.getCompleteConfiguration(DataflowApplication.class))
            .properties(new Properties())
            .run("--spring.cloud.function.definition=echo")) {
      InputDestination source = context.getBean(InputDestination.class);
      OutputDestination target = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);

      GenericMessage<byte[]> inputMessage = new GenericMessage<>("hello".getBytes());

      source.send(inputMessage);
      assertThat(target.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo("hello".getBytes());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't add `@SpringBootTest` to the test class?

Comment: @GaryRussell - I've tried it both ways ... with and without springboottest

Comment: Oh; you are using `SpringApplicationBuilder`; sorry, missed that. See [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by doing the following:

```
SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=reverse"})
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
public class EchoTransformerTest {

  @Autowired private InputDestination input;

  @Autowired private OutputDestination output;

  @Test
  public void testTransformer() {
    this.input.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>("hello".getBytes()));
    assertThat(output.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo("olleh".getBytes());
  }
}
```

and adding an application.yml to the `test/resources` this ensures that we don't read the src/resources application properties.

Another way was to explicitly define
`@TestPropertySource(locations= "test.yml")`