# How to merge application.properties with application-default.properties and include in other test profiles with Spring Boot >2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

We would like to merge `src/main/resources/application.properties` with additional default properties when running tests which in turn should be included by other (test) properties files activated via specific profiles in our Spring Boot application.

Up until Spring Boot 2.4 this worked quite well by having all common test properties in `src/test/resources/application-default.properties` to keep things DRY. Those were then automatically merged with the ones from `src/main/resources/application.properties` by Spring [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test)]. This allowed us to have our own set of default properties without requiring tests to specify an `@ActiveProfiles("default")`.

Other (test) profiles could then have their own application-<profile>.properties with `spring.profiles.include=default` and then further extend the defaults.

With Spring Boot 2.4 I'm struggling with the new "rules":

- I can no longer load application-default.properties from application-<profile>.properties since `spring.profiles.include` is no longer allowed in non profile-specific documents [[2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide#profile-groups)].
- I don't want to introduce a `src/test/resources/application.properties` since I don't want to repeat everything from `src/main/resources/application.properties`. Also I don't want to load any activate any test-related profiles in the app's properties.

It looks like one solution could be to explicitly add `spring.profiles.include=default` to `src/main/resources/application.properties` to force the application to include the properties file with default properties which will work as before when it comes to running the actual application but consider `src/test/resources/application-default.properties` when running the tests.

Is this the way to go or are there smarter solutions to tackle this problem and still keep the properties free of redundancies?

Answer (score 0):

**spring.profiles.active=dev**

add this config in application.properties file

[image]

Comment: Activating a profile is just one step to load the correct properties. However in my question I'm asking about correct properties file structuring for test to merge with `src/main/resources/application.properties` and enable property file inclusion with Spring Boot 2.4+.