# Spring boot application fails to start when adding junit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

I am trying to add tests to my Spring boot app, but when I do, the application fails to start.

I have a custom jwt authorazation class to validate jwt, I am not sure if this causes any issue?

```
@Component
public class JwtCustomValidator {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogDeletionJob.class);

    private static final String TAG = "JwtCustomValidator";

    public void validateAudience(Jwt jwt) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("validate audience JWT AUDIENCE: " + jwt.getAudience().toString());
        if (!jwt.getAudience().contains(System.getenv("oauthAudience"))) {
            //System.out.println("\nAUDIENCE NOT AUTHORIZED!\n");
            logger.warn(TAG, "AUDIENCE NOT AUTHORIZED!" + jwt.getAudience());
            throw new Exception("wrong audience");
        }
        logger.info(TAG, "audience validated");
    }

    public void validateRole(final Jwt jwt, final String role) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("validate roles JWT ROLES: " + jwt.getClaim("roles").toString());
        if (!((List<String>) jwt.getClaim("roles")).contains(role)) {
            //System.out.println("\nROLE NOT AUTHORIZED!\n");
            logger.warn(TAG, "ROLE NOT AUTHORIZED!" + jwt.getClaim("roles").toString());
            throw new Exception("Not sufficient role, UnAuthorized");
        }
        logger.info(TAG, "role validated");
    }
}
```

Here is my security configuration class with the antmatchers:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerSecurityConfigs extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/v1/books/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "api/v1/books/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "api/v1/books/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "api/v1/books/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/v1/lending/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "api/v1/lending/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "api/v1/lending/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "api/v1/lending/**").hasAuthority("ALLOW-allowedtraffic")
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt());
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' in your configuration.

2022-09-12 10:05:57,294 ERROR [main] org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@55787112] to prepare test instance [backend.controllers.MyAppListControllerTest@5488b5c5]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$JwtConfigurer.getJwtDecoder(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$JwtConfigurer.getAuthenticationProvider(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:428)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.getAuthenticationProvider(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:335)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.init(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:254)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.init(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:315)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:305)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54592', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Not sure where to start, I didn't find any thread here that solved yet. Please explain this to me, would really appreciate!

Edits:
I have one regular app.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=${logLvl}
spring.datasource.url=${dbConnStr}
spring.datasource.username=${dbUser}
spring.datasource.password=${dbPw}

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=com.backend.hibernat.CustSQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
server.port=8081

myAppPath=${myAppPath}

tenantId=123-tenant-id-456
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://issues-uri
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://keys
```

And one under test/resources:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
# spring.datasource.x
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
#settings
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
#app settings
```

Comment: The unit test fails not the app :). But that is maybe nitpicking. But you enabled JWT/oauth2 so yuou need to add some beans tot he context. You haven't thus it fails when the test is trying to start the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test is a ctroller unit-test, maybe should you just `@MockBean JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;`

### PS

For roles checking instead of your custom JWT validator, maybe could you configure an authorities converter (from Keycloak roles rather than scopes) and have Authentication converter use this authorities converter.

This would enable you to:

- write security expressions like `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('foo')")` or equivalents in security config
- unit test access control

Sample in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers)

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into this AutoConfigureMockMvc and MockBean at the moment, do you have any suggestion on where to read up on this topic? 
As for the roles checking, I only have 1 role at the moment. But will check that out too, thanks for the article

Comment: Well, the article above makes use of `@WebmvcTest` (which auto-configured MockMvc) and `@mockBean`... For more extensive doc, just use Spring one.

Answer (score 0):

The following is written in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html):

> If the application doesn’t expose a JwtDecoder bean, then Spring Boot
> will expose the above default one.

Here is how default JwtDecoder implementation looks like:

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri);
}
```

My guess is that you didn't specify `issuer-uri` in your property file, so Spring fails to autoconfigure bean above.

In a Spring Boot application, to specify which authorization server to use, simply do:

```
 spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://idp.example.com/issuer
```

Where `idp.example.com/issuer` is the value contained in the iss claim for JWT tokens that the authorization server will issue. Resource Server will use this property to further self-configure, discover the authorization server’s public keys, and subsequently validate incoming JWTs

Comment: Hi, thanks for this explanation. Do I need to add the issuer and other info in my test application.properties residing in test/resources?

Comment: As far as I know property file  src/main/resources/application.properties is enough. If you have application.properties under src/main/resources and the same application.properties under src/test/resources, which application.properties gets picked up, depends on how you are running your tests. You can read more about that here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test

Comment: You don't want your unit tests to contact authorization-server to fetch JWT public key => mock JWT decoder. Actually, you don't want to decode JWTs at all during tests => just populate test security-context with a test annotation (`@WithMockJwtAuth` or alike) or a MockMvc request post processor (`org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt` or alike)