# Override a main property with test one

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application production properties, I have a bunch of settings.

- `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
some.property.one=abc
some.property.two=def
some.property.to-override=123
```

I'd like to have **ALL** of the properties with the same values in my test `application.properties` with **ONE** change. Meanwhile I'd rather not copy-and-paste main's `application.properties`, so it would look like this:

- `src/test/resources/application.properties`

```
some.property.to-override=456
```

But - obviously - the `some.property.one` & `some.property.two` settings stay the same in test.

Comment: "*Meanwhile I'd rather not copy-and-paste main's `application.properties`...*" - What exactly is wrong with this approach? And what would you want instead?

Comment: @Turing85 well, that would be a lot of code repeated. Later, when the main `application.properties` changes, I'd have to change it in tests as well, and if I forget to do so, then I may run into problems which won't be obvious at first glance. What would I want instead? Well, as I've specified in the main post - I'd like application.properties (in test) to override the specified properties, not entirely replace the whole configuration.

Comment: The second part of  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021819/4216641) by [Mohnish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205230/mohnish) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override default Spring-Boot application.properties settings in Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create `application–test.properties` file in the `src/test/resources`. It will allow you to override only specific properties.
Checkout this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties). You're interested in "5. Spring Profiles":

> In this section, we’ll learn how to handle our issue by using Spring Profiles. Unlike the previous method, this one merges properties from the default file and the profiled file.

I hope it helps.